# Write JSON into Excel and send in response API

Tags: json, django, excel, python-3.x, api

I am stuck in a problem that I need to send the excel file in the response of an API but the data is a huge amount.
The data is coming from Django model query and then I am iterating it and saving to a variable like:

```
data=[
  {
    'title': 'xxxx',
    'website': 'xxxx',
    'state': 'CA ',
    'second_followup': None,
    'fourth_followup': datetime.datetime(2017-5-3-0-0-tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'first_followup': None,
    'first_reponse': '',
    'type': 'a',
    'email_status': 'xxx',
    'team_size': 0,
    'second_reponse': '',
    'bed_count': 0,
    'created_at': datetime.datetime(2016-8-30-0-0-tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'aum': 0,
    'bounce': None,
    'lead_status': 'xxxx',
    'founded_year': '0000',
    'third_followup': None,
    'last_name': 'xxxx',
    'address': 'xxxx',
    'email': 'xxxx',
    'created_by': 'xxxx',
    'specialties': 'xx',
    'response_date': None,
    'first_name': 'xxxx ',
    'zip': 'xxxx',
    'company_source': 'xxxx',
    'revenue': 5.0,
    'company_name': 'xxxx',
    'fax_number': '0',
    'inital_contact': datetime.datetime(2017-5-3-0-0-tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'contact_number': '0',
    'domain1': 'xxx',
    'city': '0',
    'country': 'USA',
    'industry': 'xxx',
    'department': 'a',
    'domain2': 'xxx',
    'contact_source': 'xxx',
    'fifth_followup': None
  },
  {
    'title': 'xxxx',
    'website': 'xxxx',
    'state': 'CA ',
    'second_followup': None,
    'fourth_followup': datetime.datetime(2017-5-3-0-0-tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'first_followup': None,
    'first_reponse': '',
    'type': 'a',
    'email_status': 'xxx',
    'team_size': 0,
    'second_reponse': '',
    'bed_count': 0,
    'created_at': datetime.datetime(2016-8-30-0-0-tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'aum': 0,
    'bounce': None,
    'lead_status': 'xxxx',
    'founded_year': '0000',
    'third_followup': None,
    'last_name': 'xxxx',
    'address': 'xxxx',
    'email': 'xxxx',
    'created_by': 'xxxx',
    'specialties': 'xx',
    'response_date': None,
    'first_name': 'xxxx ',
    'zip': 'xxxx',
    'company_source': 'xxxx',
    'revenue': 5.0,
    'company_name': 'xxxx',
    'fax_number': '0',
    'inital_contact': datetime.datetime(2017-5-3-0-0-tzinfo=<UTC>),
    'contact_number': '0',
    'domain1': 'xxx',
    'city': '0',
    'country': 'USA',
    'industry': 'xxx',
    'department': 'a',
    'domain2': 'xxx',
    'contact_source': 'xxx',
    'fifth_followup': None
  },... and so on
]
```

In above I have more than 10000 data, So how I can write these data into excel file and sent that file it to the API response so user can download the file. File will not save on server this is an another requirement

JSON is not saved in any file it is created while iterating the response of the Django Model Query

Answer (score 0):

Send the variable to the client side, create a temporary JSON file and use javascript with [Json2Flat](https://github.com/opendevl/Json2Flat) to convert it to `.csv`.

This library converts JSON documents to CSV.
It uses google-Gson and JsonPath for conversion. You can delete the JSON file later on or send it as an alternative to the client.

Comment: Currently, we are doing the same sending this variable to client side and using pagination but It taking a long time to render this data into File and after taking a long time it will download. So I think I need to handle from backend

Comment: You cannot help with the download as such as it depends upon network infra. Look, you have two options - either create the file at the server and make it available for download, maybe delete the file after a while or send the data in a serialised way and create the CSV using client's compute resources. Can you think of any other way?

Comment: Thanks, I will try the first option to create a file on the server because currently, we are doing the same to send data from server rest handled from the client side. One more thing is possible either on server or client side that If I send all data at once without pagination then it won't get the timeout error.

Comment: But you need to still store it in a variable or file if you want to eventually produce a CSV. Let my answer know if it worked :)

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava My pleasure :) It is an interesting thing and I too would want to optimise the efficiency as much as possible!